# Calculate difference between time in DB and Current Time

Tags: php

First off - I am using the `MySQLi Procedural` method of using `MySQL` via `PHP`

I am trying to create a way click a button to set a "timer". From what I understand, the best way to do this (on a dynamic timer - IE: 5 minutes from click) is to calculate what the `time()` would be 5 minutes from "now".

I want to save this to a DB in case the user disconnects from the page and reconnects (username/password login). This way, when they log back in, it would keep their remaining time.

Now for the code:

I am using this to pull my DT variable from SQL (YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS):

```
$expirationTime = new DateTime();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $expirationTime = $row['workTimer'];
    }
}

$time = strtotime($expirationTime);
$expirationTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

Then I pull the `current time`:

```
$currentTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I have done `echo`s on both of these and they are displaying correctly. What I want to do now is figure out the difference. I have tried multiple ways of doing this, but nothing seems to work. Most recently I did:

```
$countdown = $currentTime->diff($expirationTime);
$countdown = $countdown->format("Y-m-d H:i:s", $countdown);
```

with an error of `Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on a non-object in...`

What might be the problem?

Thanks!

---

I have updated some of the codes per the comment's suggestions to:

```
$currentTimeT = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$currentTime = strtotime($currentTimeT);

$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $expirationTime);
$expirationTime = strtotime($expirationTime);

$countdown = $currentTime->diff($expirationTime);
$countdown = $countdown->format("Y-m-d H:i:s", $countdown);
echo "C ".$currentTime."<br/> E ".$expirationTime."<br/>D ".$countdown;
```

Same Error.

Comment: `$currentTime` is a string, not a `DateTime`.

Comment: take a look at date_create()

Comment: Don't convert the times to strings before comparing them.

Comment: updated - still isn't working

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the least elegant solution but you could cut your to timestrings both into "d,m,y,h,i,s"-substrings and feed them to http://php.net/manual/de/function.mktime.php. Then you calc the difference of the timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

date_diff — Returns the difference between two **DateTime objects**

and you are passing non-object to function diff()

See this [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

I solved your issues on my side give it a try:

```
$time = "2016-09-1 04:45:54";
$time = strtotime($time);
$currentTime = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$expirationTime = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$time));
$countdown = $currentTime->diff($expirationTime);
$countdown1 = $countdown->format("%H:%I:%S");
print_r($countdown1);die;
```